# lerna publish push to npm, but not updating dependencies

Tags: npm, github-actions, package.json, monorepo, lerna

My Monorepo is currently managed by Lerna.js.
It all works fine except for the GitHub actions workflow I use to automate the npm publishing.

The situation is as follows:

I update `packages/types-lib`, then update `packages/server` with new types.
Upon completion, I push everything to GitHub, and the action is bumping `packages/types-lib` version.
However, it does not update the `packages/types-lib` listed in `packages/server` as a dependency.
Locally, it works, but not in the workflow...

Here is my workflow code:

```
name: Publish To NPM
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: "Checkout"
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0

  - name: "Use NodeJS 16.14.2"
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '16.14.2'

  - name: "Setup npm"
    run: |
      npm set @pastelabs:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
      npm set "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}"

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      yarn lerna bootstrap

  - name: Run builds # Run build of all packages
    run: yarn lerna run build

  - name: Run tests # Run tests of all packages
    run: yarn lerna run test

  - name: "Version and publish to NPM" # Interesting step
    env:
      NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
    run: |
      git config user.name "${{ github.actor }}"
      git config user.email "${{ github.actor}}@users.noreply.github.com"
      
      if [ ${{ github.base_ref }} = develop ]; then
        npx --yarn lerna version patch --exact --no-private --conventional-commits --conventional-prerelease --preid beta --yes
      else
        npx --yarn lerna version patch --exact --no-private --conventional-commits --conventional-graduate --yes
      fi
      
      npx --yarn lerna publish from-git --yes --exact
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to solve this?

Comment: After spending hours debugging, I successfully resolved the issue. I made the following changes in the lerna.json file:
{
  "version": "independent" -> "Fixed"
}

This adjustment allowed me to address the problem.
Although it necessitates updating all package versions rather than just the changed one, I found that the 'independent' option did not function as expected.

Additionally, it's noteworthy that Lerna has been deprecated. Consequently, we have transitioned away from it and are now utilizing Turborepo by Vercel.